# Highmaps: legendItemClick doesn't work when there are dataClasses in colorAxis, anyone have a workaround?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I've built a Highmaps map where states are colored according to their ranking. I set that up like this:

```
             colorAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        maxColor: 'blue',

             dataClasses: [{
                   from:0,
                    to: 3.000,
                    color:'#6497b1'
                }, {
                    from: 3.001,
                    to: 4.500, 
                     color:'#005b96'
                }, {
                    from: 4.510,
                    to: 7.000,
                     color:'#03396c'
                }, {
                    from: 7.001,
                    to: 10.000,
                    color:'#011f4b'
                }]
                    },

         legend: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Desarrollo democratico',
                    style: {
                        color: ( // theme
                            Highcharts.defaultOptions &&
                            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend &&
                            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.title &&
                            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.title.style &&
                            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.title.style.color
                        ) || 'black'
                    }
                },
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                floating: true,
                layout: 'vertical',
                valueDecimals: 3,
                symbolRadius: 5,
                symbolHeight: 14
            },
```

It works as expected. However, I would like to disable the default behavior in which when you click on a legend category it hides the corresponding states from the map. Generally, this can be accomplished by adding legendItemClick to plotOptions and setting it to return false, as follows:

```
        plotOptions: { //For point links
            series: {
              events: {
                legendItemClick: function (e) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
```

However, after several hours of researching its evident that there is a known HighCharts bug that prevents legendItemClick from working when there are dataClasses in the colorAxis object: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9246

There's a workaround in the forum at the previous link, but I haven't had any luck getting it to work. Does anyone out there have a solution for this?

Here's a JSFiddle illustrating the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/sstoker/3cdaqkyx/

As an alternative, if anyone knows how to make legendItemClick highlight the corresponding states rather than hiding them, that would work as well. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent hiding the states, you can overwrite the `setItemEvents` method:

```
(function(H) {
    H.Legend.prototype.setItemEvents = null;
})(Highcharts)
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/usaveL4w/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Works perfectly! Thx!

Comment: perfect, what if I want change the state's color on click the legend,what should I do ?

Comment: Hi @jjzjx118_2, You can overwrite `setVisible` method in `Point` prototype. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lh5y6m1t/